# Как открыть файлы формат .osm в Blender

Tags: blender

Как открыть файлы формат .osm в Blender, для 3д города

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно активировать соответствующий адон. Зайдите в User Preferenses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> -> Вкладка Add-ons (1) -> Категория Export-Import(2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно воспользоваться поиском (3) чтобы быстро найти аддон в списке.
Активируйте адон нажав на чекбокс рядом с его названием(4).

Не забудьте сохранить настройки (5)

После активации аддона можно будет импортировать файлы через меню File -> Import

Answer (score 0):

Скачать плагин blender-osm бесплатно можно [здесь](https://gumroad.com/l/blender-osm). Исходный код плагина blender-osm находится на [Github](https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-osm/tree/release). Там же на Github находится [документация](https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-osm/wiki/Documentation).